# Правильное ли написание "не полномочен"?

Tags: орфография

Он, исходя из буквального толкования текста кодекса, не полномочен их производить — как пишется «не полномочен»?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в предложении надо обособить деепричастный оборот *"исходя из буквального толкования текста кодекса"*, во-вторых, лучше сказать *"не уполномочен"*, по-моему, так как слово *"полномочен"* крайне редко встречается в русском языке.

Comment: Это не деепричастный оборот. "Исходя из" - союз. Обособление обычно возможно и нужно, но наверняка сказать можно только при рассмотрении контекста.

Comment: "Исходя из" в данном предложении производный предлог.

Comment: Да, предлог. Запутался слегка - и чуть было вас в том не обвинил.

Answer (score 1):

Раздельно. С краткими причастиями вообще НЕ всегда раздельно (ну кроме некоторых экзотических случаев).
Но вообще-то очень тяжело читается необособленное "исходя из буквального толкования". Не знаю без контекста, возможны ли тут запятые, но очень хочется поставить хотя бы парные тире.

Вот по поводу обособления "исходя из":

*Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «исходя из», обычно обособляются (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу).*
©[gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru)

Answer (score 0):

Не вполне согласен с "Валентин".

1. Обороты с "исходя из", "начиная с", если они утратили глагольность, не выделяются запятыми.
2. Заменив "полномочен" на "уполномочен", мы меняем смысл слова. "Уполномочен" - это краткое причастие, обозначающее признак предмета, над котороым только что совершено действие. "Полномочен" - это скорее краткое прилагательное, обозначающее постоянный, или длительное время существующий признак.
3. Что касается частицы НЕ,то на этот счет у Розенталя есть правило: частица НЕ пришется слитно при утверждении и раздельно - при отрицании. В данном случае здесь скорее утверждение, т.е. надо писать слитно.